# Automatically generate all help documentation for Click commands

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

Is there a way to generate (and export) help documentation using click for all commands and subcommands?

For example,

`cli --help all --destination help-docs.txt`

would generate help for commands and subcommands following the

`cli command subcommand`

format and put them into the `help-docs.txt` file.

The only way I can think that I would accomplish this is to use

`cli command subcommand --help`

on every subcommand that I wanted to generate help for and `cat` the output to a file, but it would be nice if there where an easier way to accomplish this using Click `--help` functionality.

Comment: I do not think this is natively possible. Would a solution requiring program changes be acceptable?

Comment: @StephenRauch yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code will do for Click 7, using mostly documented APIs. You'd basically call `recursive_help` somewhere, e.g. as a separate subcommand, and pass it your top-level group object.

```py
def recursive_help(cmd, parent=None):
    ctx = click.core.Context(cmd, info_name=cmd.name, parent=parent)
    print(cmd.get_help(ctx))
    print()
    commands = getattr(cmd, 'commands', {})
    for sub in commands.values():
        recursive_help(sub, ctx)
```

**Update 2019-10-05**:
one way to use this, assuming `cli` is a `click.group`, would be:

```py
@cli.command()
def dumphelp():
    recursive_help(cli)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `click` package, I know two cool solutions:

1. Is to use [click-man](https://pypi.org/project/click-man/) to auto-generate Python `click` CLI `man page`.
2. Is to use [md-click](https://pypi.org/project/md-click/) to auto-generate Python `click` CLI help in `md file` format.